# Yii CMenu active item not being set

Tags: php, yii

I'm using Yii's CMenu to generate menu in the following way:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu', array(
        'items'=>$this->mainMenu,
        'lastItemCssClass'=>'mitem-last',
        'activeCssClass'=>'mitem-active',
        'activateParents'=>true
));
```

I am displaying this menu on page `index.php?r=site/home` and was expecting the following menu item to have `mitem-active` class:

```
[2] => Array
(
    [label] => test
    [url] => /index.php?r=site/home
)
```

However the item is rendered as

```
<li><a href="/index.php?r=site/home">test</a></li>
```

If I'm not mistaken `index.php?r=site/home` has route `site/home` (which is also the output of `$this->route`), and as a matter of fact the link was created using

```
$link['url']=$this->createUrl(current($mitem['url']),$params);
```

where `current($mitem['url'])` outputs `site/home` and `$params` is just `array()`.

Am I missing something?

**EDIT:** `$this->mainMenu` is an array made up off multiple `$link`s built in a loop (from xml).

```
$this->mainMenu = array();
foreach($xml->mitem as $mitem){
    $link=array();

    ... compute some values like $link['label'], $params etc ...
    $link['url']=$this->createUrl(current($mitem['url']),$params);
    $this->mainMenu[]=$link;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For CMenu, "items" array format is:

```
array(
    array('label'=>'Home', 'url'=>array('site/index')),
    array('label'=>'About', 'url'=>array('/site/page', 'view'=>'about')),
    array('label'=>'Contact', 'url'=>array('/site/contact')),
)
```

not

```
array(
    array('label'=>'Home', 'url'=>'index.php?r=site/index'),
    array('label'=>'About', 'url'=>'index.php?r=site/page&page=about'),
    array('label'=>'Contact', 'url'=>'index.php?r=site/contact'),
)
```

If your item looks like this:

```
array('label'=>'Home', 'url'=>'index.php?r=site/home'),
```

It does not work.
Your item must be like this:

```
array('label'=>'Home', 'url'=>array('site/home')),
```

Comment: Absolutely right - Sorry I didn't ask this question too well - the format of the array is correct, the links are being displayed properly with proper `href` and labels, just not proper class. I have updated my question to explain how the array is generated in more detail.

Comment: Actually, the 'url' in items can be either a string or an array:  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CMenu#items-detail

Comment: Yes @ernie , you are right. But look inside the **CMenu::normalizeLinks** method on line #282 `if($this->activateParents && $hasActiveChild || $this->activateItems && $this->isItemActive($item,$route)) $active=$items[$i]['active']=true;` and after it look inside the **CMenu::activateItems** method on line #303 and you will see this: `if(isset($item['url']) && is_array($item['url']) && !strcasecmp(trim($item['url'][0],'/'),$route))`. Do you see this condition?: && is_array($item['url'])

Comment: If you like to set active links from string "url" param, you must extend class "CMenu" and redefine method **CMenu::activateItems**.

Comment: Interesting . . . odd that the documentation suggests you can use a string or an array, but for CMenu::activateItems, it must be an array . . .